# beginRadialGradientFill not drawing when running EaselJS under CocoonJS on Android 4.0.3

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, easeljs, cocoonjs

I am writing a game that uses the EaselJS HTML5 canvas library, and I am attempting to use Ludei's CocoonJS to deploy it to various platforms, starting with different versions of Android.

I am attempting to use the following to draw a radial gradient on the canvas:

```
shape.graphics.beginRadialGradientFill(['red', 'green'], [0, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, radius).drawCircle(0, 0, radius);
```

On an HTC Sensation handset running Android 4.0.3, if I run the game under the CocoonJS Launcher and use Canvas 2D/WebGL, no filled circle appears. Strangely enough, if I use Webview, the circle appears correctly (albeit at reduced performance). This is true whether using the latest 2.0.0.beta or 1.4.7 version of the Launcher.

The circle also appears correctly when running the game natively in a browser (not under CocoonJS).

If I use beginFill rather than beginRadialGradientFill, then the circle appears correctly even when using Canvas 2D/WebGL.

There are no clues in the CocoonJS Launcher's console as to why this issue might be occurring.

On a Samsung Galaxy S4 handset running Android 4.4.2, beginRadialGradientFill works as expected when using Canvas 2D/WebGL.

Have you come across this issue with beginRadialGradientFill on older versions of Android, and if so, did you arrive at a solution?

Comment: This could be an issue with EaselJS beginGradientFill -- I have seen it on Android devices before. We will look into it.

Comment: It looks like CocoonJS doesn't support that in the Canvas2D View: http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/200807787-HTML5-feature-list - I could only find `createGradient` but no `createRadialGradient`

Comment: Thanks @olsn - it looks like that is the actual issue. Naively, I tried using createRadialGradient to draw to a temporary canvas, and creating an EaselJS.Bitmap from that canvas (thereby bypassing beginGradientFill altogether), but have the same problem under Android 4.0.3: nothing appears. I shall look for an alternative method of creating the visual output I want.